# Why won't MediaInfo CLI let me isolate "Inform='Other'" tags?

Tags: mediainfo

I'm trying to use MediaInfo CLI (v0.7.77 on Mac OS X 10.9.5) to grab the first-frame timecode of QuickTime files using this Inform= syntax:

```
mediainfo --Inform="Other;%TimeCode_FirstFrame%" FILENAME.MOV
```

But it seems that MediaInfo ignores the existence of the "Other" section of the MediaInfo dump. It just outputs all of the file's metadata, as if I didn't enter an Inform= option at all.

However if I do something like this...

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%ColorSpace%" FILENAME.MOV
```

It simply returns "YUV", as expected, with no extraneous information.

So why won't my example using the `Other;` option work?

Here's an example of what I get when I do a `language=raw` dump of a typical source file:

> 

```
General
CompleteName                     : /Volumes/SCARY_RAID/projects.local/WaikikiStock.local/KBank-BrollSelects_20151026.local/resolve_renders/waikiki_selects/667_2942_01-0001_1920x1080-23.976.mov
Format                           : QuickTime
Format/Info                      : Original Apple specifications
FileSize/String                  : 380 MiB
Duration/String                  : 17s 59ms
OverallBitRate_Mode/String       : VBR
OverallBitRate/String            : 187 Mbps
Encoded_Date                     : UTC 2015-10-30 21:55:35
Tagged_Date                      : UTC 2015-10-30 21:55:41
Encoded_Library/String           : Apple QuickTime

Video
ID/String                        : 1
Format                           : ProRes
Format_Version                   : Version 0
Format_Profile                   : 422 HQ
CodecID                          : apch
Duration/String                  : 17s 59ms
BitRate_Mode/String              : VBR
BitRate/String                   : 187 Mbps
Width/String                     : 1920 pixel3
Height/String                    : 1080 pixel3
DisplayAspectRatio/String        : 16:9
FrameRate_Mode/String            : CFR
FrameRate/String                 : 23.976 fps2
ColorSpace                       : YUV
ChromaSubsampling                : 4:2:2
ScanType/String                  : Progressive
Bits-(Pixel*Frame)               : 3.761
StreamSize/String                : 380 MiB (100%)
Encoded_Library/String           : abm0
Language/String                  : en
Encoded_Date                     : UTC 2015-10-30 21:55:35
Tagged_Date                      : UTC 2015-10-30 21:55:41
colour_primaries                 : BT.709
transfer_characteristics         : BT.709
matrix_coefficients              : BT.709
matrix_coefficients_Original     : BT.709

Other
ID/String                        : 2
Type                             : Time code
Format                           : QuickTime TC
Duration/String                  : 17s 59ms
TimeCode_FirstFrame              : 15:02:53:00
TimeCode_Striped/String          : Yes
Title                            : Untitled
Language/String                  : en
Encoded_Date                     : UTC 2015-10-30 21:55:41
Tagged_Date                      : UTC 2015-10-30 21:55:41
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a MediaInfo bug, will be corrected soon.

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo.

Comment: Remind that this is open source and free, up to now you paid nothing, don't hesitate to ask for a quote if you need it.

Comment: Now fixed https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/pull/523 , in snapshots https://mediaarea.net/download/snapshots/binary and next release.